# Saving richtextbox to textfile(Notepad)

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement, file-io, save

How can I export texts in my richtextbox and save it in notepad?

Here's what I want to save so far. Do I need to put it in a string?

```
if (listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text == "Inactive")
{
   richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + listView1.Items[i].Text + " inactive on " + lbl_time.Text + "\n";
}
```

Comment: @GrantWinney Nah, I'm good.

Comment: @GrantWinney Didn't know how earlier until you gave me the link. Can I still post my solution right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a handy method for doing quick saves like this, called [`File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
File.WriteAllText(@"c:\somepath\yourFile.txt", r.Text);
```

If you don't need to update the text in the RichTextBox, you could probably just save the text like this:

```
if (listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text == "Inactive")
{
    File.WriteAllText(@"c:\somepath\yourFile.txt",
        string.Concat(richTextBox1.Text, listView1.Items[i].Text, " inactive on ", lbl_time.Text, "\n"));
}
```

Note that this will overwrite an existing file, not append to it. You didn't specify whether that matters.

If it does, and you just want to append text to a file if it exists, then use this instead:

```
File.AppendAllText(@"c:\somepath\yourFile.txt", r.Text);
```

Comment: I'm trying to make the filename current date and time but naming a file won't accept `:` in the time. is there an alernative?

Comment: Assuming that I specify to not overwriting the existing file, how can do it?

Comment: I mean saving the file without overwriting the current content.

Comment: Okay, got it really helped a lot. One more thing, `\n` doesn't work on `notepad` it just leaves a square character. Is there an alternative for line break?

Comment: Its working in my richtextbox though it still wont break in `notepad`

Answer (score 0):

It is important that how you fill the RichTextBox. I mean it is being filled in loop through or in any specific method or event.

if you are filling the RichTextBox loop through. then you should use `StringBuilder.AppendLine()` or `StringBuilder.AppendFormat()` method instead of concatenation operator `+`;

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i< listView1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text == "Inactive")
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("{0} inactive on {1}{2}", listView1.Items[i].Text,lbl_time.Text,Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
richTextBox.Text = sb.ToString();
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "MyFile.txt");
File.WriteAllText(path,richTextBox.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution though its also the same as the other solution given

```
                    if (listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text == "Inactive")
                {
                   richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + listView1.Items[i].Text + " inactive on " + lbl_time.Text + "\n";
                   File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Documents and Settings\pamojica\My Documents\" + lbl_date.Text + ".txt", richTextBox1.Text);
                }
```